# Spring Thymeleaf how to bind values of checkboxes to a collection field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, collections, thymeleaf

I want to generate, or bind, a `Project` object in Spring by using an html form that is processed by Thymeleaf. Everything works so far, only the `rolesNeeded` list field to be filled with roles by ticking checkboxes isn't working, yet.

The Project class

```
package com.floriantoenjes.instateam.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String status;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Role> rolesNeeded;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Collaborator> collaborators;

    public Project() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Role> getRolesNeeded() {
        return rolesNeeded;
    }

    public void setRolesNeeded(List<Role> rolesNeeded) {
        this.rolesNeeded = rolesNeeded;
    }

    public List<Collaborator> getCollaborators() {
        return collaborators;
    }

    public void setCollaborators(List<Collaborator> collaborators) {
        this.collaborators = collaborators;
    }
}
```

The Role class

```
package com.floriantoenjes.instateam.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The Controller

```
package com.floriantoenjes.instateam.web.controller;

import com.floriantoenjes.instateam.model.Project;
import com.floriantoenjes.instateam.model.Role;
import com.floriantoenjes.instateam.service.ProjectService;
import com.floriantoenjes.instateam.service.RoleService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ProjectController {
    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String newProjectForm(Model model) {
        List<Role> roles =  roleService.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("project", new Project());
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);

        return "edit_project";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProject(Project project) {
        projectService.save(project);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

}
```

The template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head th:replace="layout :: head('Edit Project')"></head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="site-header">
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">InstaTeam</a>
                    <a class="new-project button icon-left" href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i> New Project</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="collaborators.html">Collaborators</a></li>
                <li><a href="roles.html">Roles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div class="container wrapper">
                <form th:object="${project}" action="" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <label for="project_name"> Project Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" name="project_name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="project_description">Project Description:</label>
                        <textarea rows="4" th:field="*{description}" name="project_description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="project_status">Project Status:</label>
                        <div class="custom-select">
                        <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
                            <select th:field="*{status}" name="project_status">
                                <option value="active">Active</option>
                                <option value="archived">Archived</option>
                                <option value="not_started">Not Started</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="project_roles">Project Roles:</label>
                        <ul class="checkbox-list">
                            <li th:each="role : ${roles}">
                                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{rolesNeeded}" name="project_roles" th:value="${role.id}"/>
                                <span class="primary" th:text="${role.name}"></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button"/>
                        <a href="#" class="button button-secondary">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see `rolesNeeded` is a collection and I want to be able to tick checkboxes for roles and then on submitting the form generate a Project object with the roles assigned to the "rolesNeeded" collection. As I have put it right now with `*{rolesNeeded}` and `{role.id}` it doesn't work.

Right now I am just getting the following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Validation failed for object='project'. Error count: 1

Hopefully someone has a suggestion how to solve this or perhaps how I am able to get a more detailed error message.

Kind Regards,
Florian

Comment: Regarding the error: The most helpful approach is probably to open the Network tab in your browser's debugger and inspect the request data being sent.

Comment: Just a question regarding  "${role.id}"/>  and ${role.name}"> . Could you show your Role bean (pojo)class ?

Comment: chrylis thanks for the quick comment. I did that and I can see that the post request contains the role ids of the selected roles.

Hey Georges I added the Role class to my question.

Comment: @Florian check this quick tutorial : http://g00glen00b.be/spring-form-validation/

Comment: This tut is even much better : http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to write my own Spring Converter to convert from "String" to "Role", mark that class as a @Component and create a @Bean. Then it worked like charm.

```
@Component
public class StringRoleConverter implements Converter<String, Role> {

    @Override
    public Role convert(String source) {
        Role role = new Role();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(source);
        role.setId(id);
        return role;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
        converters.add(new StringRoleConverter());
        bean.setConverters(converters);
        return bean.getObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have created two Converters:

```
@Component
public class RoleStringConverter implements Converter<Role, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(Role role) {
        return role.getId().toString();
    }

}

@Component
public class StringRoleConverter implements Converter<String, Role> {

    @Autowired
    private RolesRepository rolesRepository;

    @Override
    public Role convert(String source) {
        return rolesRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(source));
    }

}
```

I've added them in my web configuration overwriting the addFormatters method. No need to do anything else.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = { "controllers", "services", "converters" })
@Import(value = { ThymeleafConfig.class, i18nConfig.class })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor;
    @Autowired
    private StringRoleConverter stringRoleConverter;
    @Autowired
    private RoleStringConverter roleStringConverter;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/403").setViewName("403");
        registry.addViewController("/about").setViewName("frontend/about");
        registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin/index");
        registry.addViewController("/admin/login").setViewName("admin/login");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        // habilitar procesamiento de contenido estático
       configurer.enable();
    } 

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(new CacheControlHandlerInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver provideMultipartResolver(){
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(Role.class, String.class, roleStringConverter);
        registry.addConverter(String.class, Role.class, stringRoleConverter);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone :).